# Javascript : Math.round is not working correctly for specific digits

Tags: javascript

I am facing weird issue during rounding the value using javascript. Some of the value is not rounding in correct format.

```
var n =17.955 ;
var roundedPrice;
roundedPrice = Math.round(n*100)/100;
console.log(roundedPrice); // It returns 17.95 instead of 17.96
```

It is happening for some specific values like `16.955, 17.955, 18.955, 19.955`. Except these values like `1.955, 12.955, 20.955, 27.955 ...` This round function return correct values.

**Edited : It is happening with 17.955 only. This returns correct result with 17.9555 ( 3 times 5).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate. It has to do with the inexact nature of binary representation of float values. Note that this is an issue with numbers in almost all programming languages, not just JavaScript.

Comment: The problem strats from n * 100, it returns a shaky floating point value ending in .4999999999999, where you expected it to be a solid .5

Comment: It is happening with 17.955 only. This returns correct result with 17.9555 ( 3 times 5)

Comment: @FreemanLambda : Yes, you are right. But it is happening with only `17.955 and 17.455`. For example,  If you run `17.355 * 100`, it will return `1735.5`

Comment: I have fixed my issue by using `var a = n*100;  roundedPrice = Math.round(a.toPrecision(10))/100`. Thanks for your all help guys.

Answer (score -3):

You can use either `Math.ceil()` to get the expected result.

Comment: How to tell when to use `ceil` when `floor`?

Comment: It depends on your requirement, what do you exactly want, either ceil or floor.

Comment: It seems OP wants to round using precise mathimatical way of doing it. You suggested him to use `ceil`. How would this help?

Comment: @Pritom Yury Tarabanko is trying to gently lead you to seeing why your answer is wrong. I'm more blunt. Your answer is wrong: the OP's problem is related to the inherent inaccuracy of representing arbitrary floating point numbers in two's complement binary format. It has nothing to do with picking `ceil` or `floor` over `round`. Which you should have figured out from reading the linked dupe before posting an answer.

Comment: Its not ensured that a person always give an correct answer, but that not means that you have to put a negative vote, we have not same mentality.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko : I got clue by your comment "precise" to fix my issue.